# Are browsers vulnerable to master password phishing attack?

Tags: security, browser, phishing

Can a website launch a phishing attack on a browser master password analogous to the [Lostpass phishing exploit against LastPass](https://www.seancassidy.me/lostpass.html)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If the Phishing attack is property scripted.
The idea of a Phishing attack is to get you to pass credentials.

The Lastpass solution is a cloudbased solution.  The phish was a site that was hosted somewhere by the attacker that mimics the lastpass solution. the user thinks they are logging onto the lastpass website, but in reality they are setting login and passwords into the fake website.  The phish attack has then successfully gained the username and password to the victim's Lastpass account.

As long as you are required to pass credentials on a website, a phish of this design will work, provided the attacker can "convince" you that you are on the real site of the attacker's desired target.

There are other password managers that are only stored on the device/PC, which will not work in these cases, but could be victimized by other types of attack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The FireFox password manager passwords are only stored on the device (well there is FireFox sync), but the FireFox dialogue pops up from the browser, and I guess could be spoofed. If I use the master password anywhere else, that may be a security issue if captured by a malicious website.

Comment: A man in the middle attack can be sophisticated enough to then pass the credentials on to the correct application and act as though nothing happened. This way you won't be suspicious whilst still giving them your credentials.

Comment: Yes.  This is where properly set routers and firewalls are used.  The idea is to prevent someone from seeing a website that is not hosted where it belongs.  If you look carefully in the article you mentioned in your question, the Phish site has a different url then the actual LastPass site.  As long as the attacker can get you to type in your credentials, it's a successful Phish.  Like fishing....put in some bait (fake website) and see if someone bites.

Comment: A discussion point with your users or family.  Always check the URLs.

Comment: @arcee123. Yes, classic phishing is when website X spoofs website Y to get the pw for website Y. My question concerns whether any website could spoof the native master pw popup and capture the browser master pw. A mitigation is that a master pw need not be used as a pw anywhere else on the internet, but I'd say it is likely to be the same as a ssh keychain pw or device login pw or any pw that needs to be memorized and not in a keychain. Hope that is clear. In my mind I think this is a plausible attack, so I'm not sure why I haven't found discussion specific to it.